# Cookie not setting on non secure connection express-session

Tags: node.js, session, express

I'm using express-session for my app. Cookies are set and users are authorised when deployed on Heroku which by default serves the app on a secure connection. When working locally on localhost with a non https connection the session is not initialised thus causing me to get a 401 back everytime. I cannot find any answers for this. My code is as follows:

```
app.use(session({
  name: consts.SESSION_COOKIE_NAME,
  secret: consts.SECRET_KEY,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  resave: true,
  cookie:{
    httpOnly: true,
    secure: false
  }
}));
```

Comment: Setting `secure` to `false` should do the trick. If it doesn't, you should check if the problem isn't being caused by something else. Start by checking if the cookie really isn't being set in your browser's dev tools.

Comment: Hello @robertklep in the above code snippet I provided I have set the secure cookie to false. The cookie is not being set at all so there is nothing to look at in the console. The session however is set when deployed on a https connection.

Comment: I would expect a cookie only being set if authentication works, and perhaps it's failing before that. Are you sure that the actual authentication of the user is successful?

Comment: The session is not being set no but this only happens on a non secure connection. I can't understand why it works on my deployed version which uses https as apposed to my localhost using http. I'm using a node server which sends back the response and should set it

Comment: What do you use as authentication mechanism?

Comment: I use express-session

Comment: That provides session management, but how do you authenticate users? How does the login mechanism work?

Comment: At the moment there is no authentication. It simply sets a session, that session is checked in the response if its true the user gets a set session if not, the user is redirecte to the login with a 401

Comment: Can you show the code where the session is created?

Comment: router.post('/login', function(req, res, next) {
    var username = req.body.username;
    var password = req.body.password;

    User.findOne({username: username, password: password}, function(err, user) {
      if(err) {
        console.log(err);
        res.status(500).send();
      }
      if(!user) {
        res.status(404).send();
      } else {
        req.session.user = '12345';
        res.status(200).send();
      }
    });
  });

Comment: Hmm I have no idea why it's not working, I would expect it to work, assuming that the rest of your app is set up properly (and because you have it working on Heroku, I assume it is).

Comment: Yeah it's strange :/ going to have to figure it out tonight - Thank you for the help